# Advice on using .Net WorkFlow State Machine. What would you do?

Tags: windows-services, workflow-foundation

So I've been tasked at work to write windows services to replace some old legacy VB6 WinForms apps currently running as services, consistently repeating tasks day-to-day. To give some general background, they have there own state machines built in to handle decision basing and not utilizing threading.

A lot of the senior developers here thought it would be worth a try to look into WorkFlow to replace the state machines rather than write my own business logic and try threading it programmaticly. So it's WF vs. the "Old College Try" I suppose.

My concern is that there aren't many books on the topic, and since it was implemented in .Net I've heard very little about it being used. I brought this up at work and another developer mentioned that it's because Biz Talk never really caught on and it was designed for that.

So is it broken? Do you think it will be supported long enough to not worry so much? I don't want an ill-functioning process injected into my services, my new babies at work, and then have WF's keel over. Leaving me with having to replace them with my own code in the event of an emergency; which does not seem like much of a grand scenario to me.

Any suggestions, recommendations would be super.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflow Foundation is used in Microsoft SharePoint, so I think they will continue supporting it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source project called Stateless by Nicholas Blumhardt.  It is quite flexible and very light weight.  [See my SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966950/workflow-design-dilemma-state-machine-yes-or-no/1980034#1980034) for details.

I chose this over Windows Workflow simply because I could define a state as State and thereby persist the state of my workflows back to the database using SubSonic.  Configuration consists of one XML file.  If I need to add tasks, I simply add nodes to the XML.

The each state can have a series of triggers that once satisfied will advance to appropriate state.  This framework is a single assemble and fits nicely in your domain logic.

Comment: I'll look into stateless but for my current service projects, I'm using WF 4 as I've invested a lot of time and the .Net 4.0 WF functionality has greatly improved and incorporates a marriage between WF and WCF nicely. Thanks for making me aware of another helpful framework.

Comment: No problem - it's a great framework and will run in 4.0 as well.  Something to keep in mind when building out your tool kit.