# using workflow with asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow, workflow-foundation

We have to do a project which is a web based workflow application. I have never used WWF. I am thinking should we use WWF with asp.net ?

This application has 10 tasks with multiple options (each task may have 4 options) with a good amount of data. Just like banks have customer dealing work flow applications.

I am not getting will it hard to switch to WWF ? (we have short time to deliver/ learning curve)

Please advice on this.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WF is meant for long-running asynchronous tasks. It allows you to return some data to the user while the task you started is still running. It also allows you to update the user on the tasks progress and properly handle task failures.

If your tasks are taking a lot of time to complete (too much to handle in one postback), I would have a look at WF

Answer (score 0):

You can easily integrate workflow state with Nicholas Blumhardt Stateless.  See my [SO anwser here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966950/workflow-design-dilemma-state-machine-yes-or-no/1980034#1980034)

With this framework you can quickly integrate state machine capabilities into your domain.  The state can be represented as `State<T>`, and therefore will integrate quickly into an ORM.

I recommend this to you as just different view on how to create workflows.  I have an app that has 4 workflows running in production for almost a year and have enjoyed the ability to quickly integrate new workflows into my applications quickly.