# Sample State machine Workflow implementation in ASP.net for approval workflow

Tags: asp.net, workflow-foundation-4, state-machine

In ASP.Net application, I display a list which can be in below three states -

1. Initial
2. Submitted
3. Approved

I need to write a workflow with these three state but not able to understand how do I implement triggers for these states in asp.net application as user would be changing the state as per his convenience on login. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [stateless](http://code.google.com/p/stateless/) by Nicholas Bumhardt.  See my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966950/workflow-design-dilemma-state-machine-yes-or-no/1980034#1980034) for details.  stateless is quite lightweight, are well suited for what you need.